# Kdtree insert function

Tags: c, pointers, tree, binary-tree

```
void insert_KD_tree(noKD **tree, Queue *queue, int counter) {


    if ((*tree)!=NULL) {
            *tree = new_KD_node(queue->first->pointer,NULL,NULL);
    }
    else if (((*tree)->pointer[counter]) > (queue->first->pointer[counter])) {
            counter++;
            insert_KD_tree(&(*tree)->left,queue);
    }
    else {
            counter++
            insert_KD_tree(&(*tree)->right,queue,counter);
    }
    pop(queue);
}
```

Ok, so this is basically the binary tree insertion function, but for inserting arrays to the nodes.
The arrays are stored on the queue, but I'm having a problem with the pointer to a pointer.
When I try to access the array using gdb, it gives the message that it can't access the memory location `0x10`, but if I try to access it on another function, it shows me the location just fine and I can access the array.

I've noticed that the problem is the pointer to pointer thing and if I put only one asteric when calling the `insert_KD_function`, my program can access tree->pointer without any problems.
So the problem has something to do with the pointer to pointer, it's losing the pointer reference in some way.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: When you create a new tree node, are the `left` and `right` pointers initialized to `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((*tree)!=NULL) {
```

Doesn't that mean that you *overwrite* the root if it exists? Shouldn't that be `== NULL`?

Apart from that, you should not that kd-trees don't perform very well on *updates*. If you have a lot of updates, you probably are better off with an R*-tree, which is balanced.
Otherwise, pay attention to the structure of the tree, and bulk-load it again if it becomes too unbalanced.